# Accessing sub lists one by one to count occurrences of variables in each list

Tags: python, list

I've created a list which contains the entries from a data file, split into a sublist for each line.

```
[['Susan', 'McDonald', 'rat', 'aries', '34', 'yes', '1', '0'], ['Michael', 'Fox', 'ox', 'taurus', '54', 'yes', '2', '1'], ['Fred', 'Chai', 'tiger', 'gemini', '34', 'yes', '1', '0'], ['Abedin', 'Look', 'rat', 'aries', '23', 'yes', '0', '1'], ['Carlos', 'Pantro', 'ox', 'aries', '18', 'yes', '5', '3'], ['Chang', 'Green', 'ox', 'aries', '29', 'no', '1', '4'], ['Tatiana', 'Zing', 'ox', 'taurus', '33', 'no', '0', '0'], ['Ani', 'Williams', 'rat', 'taurus', '55', 'yes', '0', '1']]
```

Each list contains a person's name, Chinese & Greek zodiac signs, age, and other data associated with the person. I'm not sure how to go through the sublists to find, for example, the average age of all people with the zodiac sign 'ox'. Any idea how I can accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

```
def displayZodiacStats(zodiacSign, sourceList):
    print(zodiacSign, "stats")
    sublists = [sourceList[x:x+8] for x in range(0, len(sourceList), 8)]

    numberOfPeople = sourceList.count(zodiacSign)

sumOfAges = 0
countOfEntries = 0
for aLine in sublists
    entries = 
    countOfEntries = countOfEntries+ 1
    sumOfAges = sumOfAges + int(entries[5])
    print(“Avg. age “ + str(sumOfAges/countOfEntries))
```

Comment: (1.) This is a duplicate. Search first. (2.) Typographical quotes (`“`) have no business in source code.

Comment: use [nametuple](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#collections.namedtuple)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (not tested but should work):

```
zodiacs = ['ox']  #you could add multiple values here to search for them all
age_list = []
for sublist in sourceList:
    age = sublist[4]
    zodiac_sign = sublist[2]
    if zodiac_sign in zodiacs:
        age_list.append(age)

print 'Average age: {}'.format(sum(age_list)/len(age_list))
```

Or for a 1 line approach to get the `age_list` list:

```
age_list = [sublist[4] for sublist in sourceList if sublist[2] in zodiacs]
```